# Upload to and Import files from google drive in angular version 12 application

Tags: angular, file, import, export, google-picker

I need to make file upload to google drive and import the file from google drive when the user clicks on a button.
I've made the configuration set-up in the google cloud platform.
But I see the integration is supported for vanilla Js and not available for Angular.